# Why is value of RSP higher than RBP as displayed in GDB?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, gdb, stack-pointer

I am inspecting a process (which has no bugs actually) with gdb.

However I noticed, when doing info registers, that `RSP` is higher than `RBP`, which is not consistent with the fact that the stack grows downwards. Is this perhaps some optimization by the compiler?

```
rbp            0x7fabaf9ba290      0x7fabaf9ba290
rsp            0x7ffdf1ffa1b0      0x7ffdf1ffa1b0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no requirement that `rbp` be used as a frame pointer. When `-fomit-frame-pointer` is active, as is the default in optimized programs, it's just used the same as any other call-saved register (e.g., `rbx`).

Comment: You're probably right since the process was actually Apache2 which should be optimized, though I can't understnd its makefiles to confirm.

Comment: @AaaBbb: If the functions don't all start with `push rbp` / `mov rbp, rsp`, and aren't full of loads/stores to keep every variable in memory at locations like `[rbp - 16]`, then it's not a debug build.  The difference in asm is very obvious in most code.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394) / [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, indeed the prologue is non conventional, at some oint it moves rdi in rbp and seems to use rbp as a "normal" register.